# In pyspark, group based on a variable field, and add a counter for particular values (which resets when variable changes)

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Create a spark dataframe from a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"b": ['A','A','A','A','B', 'B','B','C','C','D','D', 'D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D'],"Sno": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],"a": [3,-4,2, -1, -3, -1,-7,-6, 1, 1, -1, 1,4,5,-3,2,3,4, -1, -2]})

df2=spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Next I use the window partition on the field 'b'

```
from pyspark.sql import window
win_spec = (window.Window.partitionBy(['b']).orderBy("Sno").rowsBetween(window.Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
```

Add a field positive , negative based on the values and created a lambda funtion

```
df2 = df2.withColumn("pos_neg",col("a") <0)
pos_neg_func =udf(lambda x: ((x) & (x != x.shift())).cumsum())
```

tried creating a new column (which is a counter for negative values but within variable 'b'. so counter restarts when the field in 'b' changes. Also if there are consecutive -ve values, they should be treated as a single value, counter changes by 1

```
df3 = (df2.select('pos_neg',pos_neg_func('pos_neg').alias('val')))
```

I want the output as,

```
      b  Sno  a    val  val_2
0   A    1  3  False      0
1   A    2 -4   True      1
2   A    3  2  False      1
3   A    4 -1   True      2
4   B    5 -3   True      1
5   B    6 -1   True      1
6   B    7 -7   True      1
7   C    8 -6   True      1
8   C    9  1  False      1
9   D   10  1  False      0
10  D   11 -1   True      1
11  D   12  1  False      1
12  D   13  4  False      1
13  D   14  5  False      1
14  D   15 -3   True      2
15  D   16  2  False      2
16  D   17  3  False      2
17  D   18  4  False      2
18  D   19 -1   True      3
19  D   20 -2   True      3
```

In python a simple function like following works:

```
df['val'] = df.groupby('b')['pos_neg'].transform(lambda x: ((x) & (x != x.shift())).cumsum())
```

josh-friedlander provided support in the above code

Comment: Why does `val` not increase for value `B` in column `b`?

Comment: You will have a problem because you do not have any order clause ...

Comment: @cronoik, in case there are consecutive negative values, I am treating them as a single negative value. Hope that answers your question

Comment: @Steven added the orderby clause as well, there is still some issue                                           
"win_spec = window.Window.partitionBy(['b']).orderBy("b").rowsBetween(window.Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))"

Comment: @DevarshiMandal `partitionBy(['b']).orderBy("b")` is not a valid `orderBy` clause .... The result won't be idempotent, I am not sure you want that. 
**order of rows may be non-deterministic after a shuffle**

Comment: @Steven, is adding order clause really necessary? I don't want it to  be ordered. I can add another column with serial number and it under orderby clause, But is doubt it would solve the problem

Comment: @DevarshiMandal it will because your system is distributed.

Comment: It makes a difference because you want to treat consecutive negative values differently. When you can't order it, how do you decide what is consectutive?

Comment: @Steven, I have edited my question, where I added a new column 'Sno' and included it in the order clause, it is still not working. I am not sure if I am applying the lambda function correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark doesn't have a shift function, but you could work with the [lag](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) window function which gives you the row before the current row. The first window (called w) sets the value of the `val` column to 1 if the value of the `pos_neg` column is `True` and the value of the previous `pos_neg` is `False` and to 0 otherwise.
With the second window (called w2) we calculate the cumulative sum to get your desired

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = pd.DataFrame({"b": ['A','A','A','A','B', 'B','B','C','C','D','D', 'D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D'],"Sno": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],"a": [3,-4,2, -1, -3, -1,-7,-6, 1, 1, -1, 1,4,5,-3,2,3,4, -1, -2]})

df2=spark.createDataFrame(df) 

w = Window.partitionBy('b').orderBy('Sno')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('b').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0).orderBy('Sno')

df2 = df2.withColumn("pos_neg",col("a") <0)

df2 = df2.withColumn('val', F.when((df2.pos_neg == True) & (F.lag('pos_neg', default=False).over(w) == False), 1).otherwise(0))
df2 = df2.withColumn('val',  F.sum('val').over(w2))

df2.show()
```

Output:

```py
+---+---+---+-------+---+ 
|Sno|  a|  b|pos_neg|val| 
+---+---+---+-------+---+ 
|  5| -3|  B|   true|  1| 
|  6| -1|  B|   true|  1| 
|  7| -7|  B|   true|  1| 
| 10|  1|  D|  false|  0| 
| 11| -1|  D|   true|  1| 
| 12|  1|  D|  false|  1| 
| 13|  4|  D|  false|  1| 
| 14|  5|  D|  false|  1| 
| 15| -3|  D|   true|  2| 
| 16|  2|  D|  false|  2| 
| 17|  3|  D|  false|  2| 
| 18|  4|  D|  false|  2| 
| 19| -1|  D|   true|  3| 
| 20| -2|  D|   true|  3| 
|  8| -6|  C|   true|  1| 
|  9|  1|  C|  false|  1| 
|  1|  3|  A|  false|  0| 
|  2| -4|  A|   true|  1| 
|  3|  2|  A|  false|  1| 
|  4| -1|  A|   true|  2| 
+---+---+---+-------+---+
```

You may wonder why it was neccessary to have a column which allows us to order the dataset. Let me try to explain this with an example. The following data was read by pandas and got an index assigned (left column). You want to count the occurences of `True` in the `pos_neg` and you don't want to count consecuitive `True`'s. This logic leads to the `val2` column as shown below:

```
    b  Sno  a   pos_neg  val_2
0   A    1  3  False      0
1   A    2 -4   True      1
2   A    3  2  False      1
3   A    4 -1   True      2
4   A    5 -5   True      2
```

...but it depends on the index it got from pandas (order of rows). When you change the order of the rows (and the corrosponding pandas index) you will get a different result when you apply your logic to the same rows just because the order is different:

```
    b  Sno  a   pos_neg  val_2
0   A    1  3  False      0
1   A    3  2  False      0
2   A    2 -4   True      1
3   A    4 -1   True      1
4   A    5 -5   True      1
```

You see that the order of the rows is important. You might wonder now why pyspark doesn't create an index like pandas does. That is because spark keeps your data in several partitions which are distributed on your cluster and is depending on your data source even able to read the data distributedly. An index can't therefore not be added during the reading of the data. You can add one after the data was read with the [monotonically_increasing_id](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) function, but your data could already have a different order compared to your data source due to the read process.

Your `sno` column avoids this problem and guaranties that you will get always the same result for the same data (deterministic).

Comment: this is indeed great. Thanks a lot for sharing the answer in such short time. Any reason as to why the 'Sno' order changes?

Comment: I have added an explanation. I hope it makes it clear.